# What does expression begins with dash mean in shell assignment?

Tags: bash

I tryied using JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m ... in a script file. It shows error like "-Xmx1024m: command not found".

After quoting the assignment in double or single quotes, the error disappear.

And I found that the error is caused by the first dash sign. Because all assignments like "a=-bb xx yy ..." will raise the same error: it tried to run the xx as a program. It seems that shell recognize the second word as a command if the first word begins with a dash sign as long as there's no quotes in the assignment expression.

So my question is: what does assignment expression begins with dash sign mean in shell? I'm using bash as default.

Comment: Sorry, you don't understand at all.  The dash has nothing to do with it, it's the embedded spaces that delimit the assgnment and make the rest of the line a command.  `VAR=foo bar` will assign "foo" to the variable VAR and then run the command bar with that (all in a subprocess, so the variable does not affect the main shell).

Comment: @efan when you found that the error is because of the dash, did you try to falsify it by testing `a=bb xx yy`?

Comment: @muru Yes, I understand now, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you really should be quoting your variables:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
```

Because  the variable was unquoted,in your original command only `JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m` was interpreted as variable assignment,and `-Xmx1024m` as a command name. This is often refereed to as setting up environment variable for command. For instance,

```
LC_ALL=C  date +%s
```

would modify `date`'s environment with setting `LC_ALL=C` ( that is running `date` with english locale, even if you have something else set). Note the difference here - LC_ALL=C doesn't have spaces, so word splitting doesn't occur, which is what's happening in case of `JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m`

Second, the dash signifies short style of options. There's also long style, for instance `bash --posix` or `ls --format=long`.  Why dash ? Historical convention. It should be noted that POSIX standard requires only short version of the command-line arguments.